# how to prevent deault Alt+S in firefox

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am Using `jQuery` in my mvc project .i am creating keyboard shortcut for saving,cancelling ,Add new for that i am using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>,<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>,<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>,its working on chrome,on firefox  ,its <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> is not working .

i am using these codes-

```
$(document).on('keydown', function (e) {

    // e.preventDefault();
    e.preventDefault ? e.preventDefault() : event.returnValue = false;

    var key = e.which || e.keyCode;
    if (e.altKey === true && key === 78) {-Colling a Add Function
        //  AddCompany(); -i adding a new company
        alert('Are You Want to Add New Company ');
    }
    if (e.altKey === true && key === 83) {-Colling a save Function
        // funSaveCreation();- save function
        alert('Are You Want to Save Company ');
    }
    if (e.altKey === true && key === 67) {--Colling a cancel Function
        // Cancel();- cancel function
        alert('Are You Want to Cancel ');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Be aware that some browsers will not allow you to capture certain shortcuts! A working jQuery example for the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> shortcut (*Mozilla Firefox: version 51.0.1, Linux*) in a focused window:

```
$(window).keydown(function(event) {
  if(event.altKey && event.keyCode == 83) { 
    console.log("Alt+S event captured!");
    event.preventDefault(); 
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm able to prevent default shortcut of Firefox, using these codes:

```
$(document).on('keydown', function (event) {
    event = event || document.event;
    var key = event.which || event.keyCode;

    if (event.altKey === true && key === 78) {
        ShowAddtabVendors();     
    }

    if (event.altKey === true && key === 83) {
        funSaveVendor();
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
        event.disabledEventPropagation();
    }
});
```